# unknown web method using ajax/jquery

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, jquery

```
ERROR: unknown web method DoIt Parameter name: methodName
```

I'm trying to pass a date into a DB Query function backended by VB.NET but am having problems with the webside of things.

```
var dat = $("#Date").val(); //textbox with a date    

$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "file.aspx/DoIt",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: {param:dat},
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data, status) {
                        var response = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                        alert(response.message);
                        alert(status);
                    },
                    error: function (xmlRequest) {
                        alert(xmlRequest.status + ' \n\r ' + xmlRequest.statusText + '\n\r' + xmlRequest.responseText);
                    }
                });
```

The `file.aspx.vb` file:

(at the end of the file)

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Function DoIt(ByVal param As String) As String
    UpdateDB(param) 'function is above
End Function
```

I'm just not entirely sure whats going wrong or what it means ;/

Comment: can you tell us more about where you see the error message and what exactly it says?

Comment: Really just a 500 error with "unknown web method DoIt Parameter name: methodName"

Comment: ...and you are getting that error in the javascript ajax response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that might be worth checking out is to ensure that your database is setup to receive a datetime datatype.

Also something to try in your web-service declaration:

```
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function DoIt(ByVal param As String) As String
    UpdateDB(param) 'function is above
End Function
```

Reference: [webservice - unknown web method parameter name methodname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543347/webservice-unknown-web-method-parameter-name-methodname)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8966737/803739).  You may need to declare the function as `Shared`

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function DoIt(ByVal param As String) As String
    UpdateDB(param) 'function is above
End Function
```